# MVEL - Error: could not access field in ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer

Tags: expression, mvel

I am newbie to MVEL. Following steps I followed

1) Downloaded latest from http://mvel.codehaus.org/Downloading+MVEL
 i.e. Download mvel2-2.2.0.jar (JDK 1.5+ required)

2) Created a simple list of custom obj

```
       class TestMVEL {
    public static void main(String[] p){
        String expr0 = "fruits[1]";
        String expr1 = "System.out.println(fruits[1]);";
        String expr2 = "foreach( f : fruits) { System.out.println(f.getName()); }";  

        System.out.println(MVEL.eval(expr0, new Basket()));//prints Fruit{name=Banana}
        MVEL.eval(expr1, new Basket());// prints Fruit{name=Banana}
        MVEL.eval(expr2, new Basket());//error
    }
}
class Basket {
   List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

   public List<Fruit> getFruits(){
     fruits.clear();
     fruits.add(new Fruit("Apple"));
     fruits.add(new Fruit("Banana"));
     fruits.add(new Fruit("Orange"));
     return fruits;
   }
}

class Fruit { 
    private String name; 
    public Fruit(String n){
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Fruit{" + "name=" + name + '}';
    }
}
```

3) Getting below error

> Exception in thread "main" [Error: f.getName(): Class
>   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer 
>   can not access a member of class test.Fruit with modifiers "public"] [Near :
>   {... foreach( f : fruits) { System.out.println(f.getName()); } ....}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class Fruit needs to be public.

```java
public class Fruit...
```